# Oauth 2.0 in Magento 2.2 with how to access the token

Tags: magento2.2, oauth, webapi

Can please give example to access the magento 2 api by using oauth 2

Comment: Above Solution provide by Aditya Shah is for OAuth V1 and not for OAuth V2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141779)

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 is compliant Oauth 1.0a only

Answer (score 0):

> Open the System > Extensions > Integrations

[image]

> Add New Integration

[image]

> Set the integration **Name** and other settings, then specify your
>   Magento 2 back-end password in the **Your Password** field

[image]

> Switch to the **API** sidebar tab and select the resources which will
>   be available to **OAuth clients**:

[image]

> Press the **Save** button. The **integration** will be saved and the
>   **Integrations** list will be shown again. Press the **Activate** link in the integration row:

[image]

> A confirmation screen will be shown. Press the **Allow** button

[image]

> The credentials screen will be shown.
>     Use them in your third-party software to access your Magento 2 as OAuth server.
>
> **You will see:**
>
> - Consumer Key
> - Consumer Secret
> - Access Token
> - Access Token Secret
>
> Copy it to somewhere, then press the **Done** button.

[image]

> The integration will be saved and the **Integrations** list will be
>   shown again. You will see your integration in the **Active** state:
>   [image]

Comment: This applies to oauth1 not oauth2.