# Admin direct login with URL

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin-login

I want to give certain admin user to ability to login using a direct link. The main admin will send a link in a email to sub admin users. The sub users will click on the link and they will directly login (without entering the `Username` and `Password`) on some page.

Is there a way to do this in Magento 2 or do i need something to do this feature?

Comment: magento provides session ids for customers

Comment: built-in session manager that generates a new random session ID with high entropy after login.

Comment: Any reference? Can you give me  any lnks here

Comment: Please give the inks in Ans. So i could mark as found.

Comment: Actually i have a solution but you have to customize in magento.

Comment: I can do that please give me the solution

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83897/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-avesh-naik).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

---

It is indeed not possible to pass the username and password via **query parameters** in standard `HTTP` `auth`.

- Instead, you use a special URL format, like this:
  `http://username:password@example.com/`
- this sends the credentials in the standard HTTP "**Authorization**"
  header.

It's possible that whoever you were speaking to was thinking of a custom module or code that looked at the query parameters and verified the credentials. This isn't standard HTTP auth, though, it's an application-specific thing.

NOTE : `http://username:password@example.com` will works for FireFox, Chrome, Safari BUT not for IE.

---

**Solution 2**

---

Passing **authentication** parameters in query string

When using **OAuth** or other authentication services you can often also send your **access token** in a query string instead of in an `authorization header`, so something like:

**GET**

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/1?access_token=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCD
```

> NOTE : Magento provide **OAuth** token, so you can achieve it by this
>   way.

Comment: OK. Working on the Solution. Once complete i will mark it. Thank you for the respond.

Comment: :) no issue bro.

Comment: I was able to create access token using https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175480/get-token-authentication-for-customer-logged-with-facebook-twitter-magento-2

But how to authenticate the user?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232464/oauth-2-0-in-magento-2-2-with-how-to-access-the-token/243701#243701

Comment: If you're getting token then just pass in the url.

Comment: which url i should pass the token?

Comment: How can i authenticate user with that token? what is the function to authenticate admin user with access token?

Comment: Did you got the token first ?

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: Then you don't need to Authenticate that token bro, token itself OAuth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83904/discussion-between-avesh-naik-and-aditya-shah).

Comment: Yes but where to pass this token?

Comment: Are you there? I need the function which will authenticate